# Problem on Windows after DualBoot (Windows 10 / Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I downloaded the ISO of the new Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, made a Bootable USB, created an empty partition next to the Windows partition. I booted with the pendrive and followed the installation of Ubuntu normally in the new partition.

My goal was to install Ubuntu 18.04 next to Windows 10 (LEGACY), but at the end of the whole installation, Ubuntu normally entered by selecting the option in GRUB. However when selecting Windows 10 in Grub, a black screen appears and stays forever.

I've tried all the Grub repair solutions that I found and nothing worked. The Windows option appears in Grub, but it no longer works.

I have a lot of things working inside Windows, and if you can help me with this, I'll be very grateful !!

Thank you all!

Comment: Did you backup Windows before the install?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Unfortunately not =(

Answer (score 0):

You can access your stuff in windows thru Ubuntu using the file cabinet icon. Also your HDD will contain all things IN and OF windows. Your windows is not corrupt at all, so do not delete any partitions or go crazy. Maybe try logging into bios and choosing windows at start up for now... I can not help with the grub problem..but there are many great techs on this site.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know I could access the files through Ubuntu, but I did!
But anyway I want to try recovering Windows for other uses.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes while installing Ubuntu dual-boot with Windows, Windows does get corrupted at times if you unknowingly mess up with the EFI partition or something. You can try these in order:

1. Change the Legacy Boot settings and open Windows on default.
2. Get your data backup by logging into ubuntu and access your Windows partitions normally after mounting them.
3. Last resort is reinstall Windows in the Windows boot partition without affecting your Ubuntu partition or the rest of the data partitions.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your MBR using the Boot-Repair live usb: https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ (I used the recommended repair option)

If this doesn't work, first recover Windows 10 UEFI Boot using a windows pendrive. This will make you boot directly to Windows 10 and ignore GRUB.
Steps available at http://www.thewindowsclub.com/repair-master-boot-record-mbr-windows for example. Then use Boot-Repair.

Comment: Using Boot-Repair Live-USB Has Any Difference Installing It On Ubuntu And Using? Because I already used it in Ubuntu and did not solve the problem.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you tried it and it didn't recover Windows, I would fix the UEFI boot with a Windows Pendrive, then recover GRUB using boot-repair using a live USB. I've done it before and it worked very well.

Comment: I will try this. Even if my Windows is configured in Legacy Boot, can this work?

Comment: I don't see why it would be different, it might even offer a better compatibility with boot-repair.